# Detect unsupported regex features at compile time

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, cross-browser

It seems safari has some regex features that are not well supported (lookbehind) even in it's latest version and throws some warnings:

```
register.js:298 SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier
```

Is there a way to detect, lint or transform those kind of regex automatically with webpack or any other tool at compile time, because those kind of errors tend to slip through tests?

In my case this is the regex causing an error

```js
/(?<!\.|^)\.(?!\.+|$)/
```

It should match a dot in the middle of the string but not match a succession of dots, I'm trying to get a good equivalent for this regex but I am getting nowhere so far

```js
const tests = [
'test.123.test',
'.test',
'test.',
'test.3..test',
];
//Expected
tests.forEach((test) => console.log(test.split(/(?<!\.|^)\.(?!\.+|$)/)));
//Actual
tests.forEach((test) => console.log(test.match(/^(([^.]*?)(?:\.)([^.]*?))*$/)));
```

Comment: Especially with Regex, you need to use web resources (like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to check for browser compatibility even *BeFORE* you get to compile time

Comment: Yes I know but sometimes you copy a piece of code without checking support or just forget, I actually knew lookbehind weren't supported in safari since last year yet I managed to forget and still used one in my code, causing trouble down the line hence why I'm looking to detect those kind of things during compilation or somewhere in CI because humans aren't always perfect :p

Comment: "Running unit tests on browsers" never heard that one before (: Test units are browser independent and run on a fake dom most of the time, I guess you mean e2e tests on something like selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.match(/^\.+[^.]*|[^.]*\.+$|(?:\.{2,}|[^.])+(?:\.+$)?/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PBZglg/1/). Details:

- `^\.+[^.]*` - one or more dots and then zero or more chars other than a dot
- `|` - or
- `[^.]*\.+$` - zero or more chars other than a dot and then one or more dots until string end
- `|`  - or
- `(?:\.{2,}|[^.])+(?:\.+$)?` - one or more two or more dots or any chars other than a dot and then an optional sequence of one or more dots at the end of string.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const tests = [
'test.123.test',
'.test',
'test.',
'test.3..test',
'test.3..test.',
'..test.3.test..'
];
for (let test of tests) {
  console.log(test.split(/(?<!\.|^)\.(?!\.+|$)/)); // Expected
  console.log(test.match(/^\.+[^.]*|[^.]*\.+$|(?:\.{2,}|[^.])+(?:\.+$)?/g)); // Actual
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer which answered correctly one part of my question, I found the answer to my second problem https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-es

Answer (score 2):

For the main part of my question, I found an [eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-es) that is able to detect ECMA features (including regex lookbehind) so by enabling the ones known to cause issues, because they can't be transpiled, it will automatically throw an error

```js
{
    "plugins": ["es"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "rules": {
        "es/no-async-iteration": "error",
        "es/no-malformed-template-literals": "error",
        "es/no-regexp-lookbehind-assertions": "error",
        "es/no-regexp-named-capture-groups": "error",
        "es/no-regexp-s-flag": "error",
        "es/no-regexp-unicode-property-escapes": "error"
    }
}
```